# Facing issue while validating the Email Address

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var EmailContainer = $('#EmailContainer');
    var url = EmailContainer.attr('data-url');
    EmailContainer.load(url, function () {
        var Emailform = $('#EmailForm');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(Emailform);
        Emailform.submit(function () {
            debugger;
            var Emailform = $(this);
            if (Emailform.valid()) {
                var SendEmailUrl = EmailContainer.attr('Json-Url');
                var UserModel = { From: $('#From').val(), To: $('#To').val(), 
                      Subject: $('#Subject').val(), 
                      Description: $('#Description').val() }
                $.post(SendEmailUrl, UserModel, function (data) {
                    Emailform.html(data);
                    Emailform.removeData('validator');
                    Emailform.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(Emailform);
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

**Model**

```
public class User
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1), 
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "From")]
        [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress,
              ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1), 
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmail")]
        [DisplayName("From Email Address")]
        public String From { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "To")]
        [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress, 
                  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1), 
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmail")]
        [DisplayName("To Email Address")]
        public String To { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "Subject")]
        [DisplayName("Subject")]
        public String Subject { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "Description")]
        [DisplayName("Description")]
        public String Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Issue - not showing validation for Invalid Email Address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Issue - not showing validation for Invalid Email Address

I can't see anywhere in your code where you did any validation. If you want to do validation then use corresponding validation attributes on your model property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1), 
      ErrorMessageResourceName = "From")]
[DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress,
      ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1), 
      ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmail")]
[DisplayName("From Email Address")]
[RegularExpression("GET A REGEX TO VALIDATE AN EMAIL FROM HERE: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html")]
public string From { get; set; }
```

Obviously the same stands true for your `To` property if this is intended to be an email:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1),
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "To")]
[DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress, 
          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource1), 
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmail")]
[DisplayName("To Email Address")]
[RegularExpression("GET A REGEX TO VALIDATE AN EMAIL FROM HERE: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html")]
public string To { get; set; }
```

So go get a regex for an email here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score -1):

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress` is not for validating the email. It is used so ASP.Net MVC can decide how to dispaly the value of the field.

You have to write your own logic for email validation.
If we apply `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress` to any property then that field will be shown with hyperlink and not as a normal text which will have a "mailTo" link added to it. Add your own logic for validating email address by writting custom data annotations.

Cheers

Comment: Are you talking about custom attributes ?

Comment: Yeah write your attribute by inheriting System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute class and add the logic to IsValid() method.